# XPath for href links based on anchor text substring

Tags: html, xml, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I have this HTML and I need to make an XPath to find all the "A1" text and get the `href` of all those elements of the page. It has multiple `A1`s in the page but I need all the `href`s.

I can't crack it.

```
<a href="./leitor.do?numero=20090&amp;keyword=ministro&amp;anchor=5975889&amp;origem=busca" class="edition" title="Folha de S.Paulo">
    <figure>
        <img src="https://acervo.folha.uol.com.br/files/flip/11/89/58/97/5975889/140/5975889.jpg" width="180" height="312.4">
    </figure>                                
    <h3>31.dez.2014</h3>                                           
    <p>
        país. Poder Novo <b>ministro</b> diz que Congresso irá ?expurgar? culpados futuro articulador polí
    </p>                                           
    <small>
        Folha de S.Paulo, Ano 94 - N° 20.090<br>                                
        A1 - 1 ocorrência                                
    </small>       
</a>
```

Comment: What would your expected outcome look like for this example?

Comment: Which _Selenium Language Binding Art_ are you using? _Java_ / _Python_ / _C#_ ? Your code trials please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//a[contains(.,"A1")]/@href
```

will return all `href` attributes on `a` elements with string values that contain an `"A1"` substring.

Comment: Note that Selenium doesn't support such expressions (XPath should return WebElement only, but not text or attribute), so to get all `@href` values, for example in Python, OP might need to use `[link.get_attribute("href") for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(.,"A1")]')]`

Comment: Thanks, @Andersson.  It's unfortunate that Selenium places such restrictions on the range of results that XPath can return, but I appreciate your helpful comment.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use XPath for that. You can use `driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text("A1")`, and on each of the returned element, call `element.get_attribute("href")`

You can combine it to one line as follows:

```
all_hrefs=[el.get_attribute("href") for el in driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text("A1")]
```

Comment: It worked, but the partial link text is a problem, because there is A11 for instance and it get's the HREF of it. But i solved with "A1 ".